# Why is there space at the beginning of my SharePoint Designer Custom Emails?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, email, workflow

Every time I setup a custom email and use the slightest bit of HTML within the email, there's a block (for lack of a better term) of dead space at the top of the email.  I can't seem to get rid of it.  I've tried different things, but I'm at the end of my rope with my skillset.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have no white space between your tags when you add/refrence it in SPD, should be one nice long string. i.e. `<table><tr><td><p><span></span></p></td></tr></table><etc...>`

Try encapsulating your content into a table or div and setting margin to 0 and/or adding a negative for the top margin.

---

Ben McCormack has an Access Form that can generate the code for you.
http://unitedsupplyco.sharepointsite.net/publicfacing/bensblog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=49

If you just look at the examples you will how the code is not 'formatted' in a clear readable way (no line breaks, indents, etc).  This is how the email template needs to be.

I would also strip out all your CSS code and see if the layout is working without that, then start adding back your CSS and you'll find what's causing your problem.

Not sure how much more I can give you without seeing a pic of your 'white space' problem and the actual code you are using.

Comment: Just to give you an update, I added this bit of code to my container:

<div cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="position:absolute;top:0px">

and I'm experiencing the same result.  Is this what you were talking about?

Comment: I've tried this too and it doesn't work:

<div cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="position:absolute;top:-50px">

I get the same results...

Comment: I have also tried this:

<div cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="position:absolute; margin-top:-50px">

<div border="0" width="100%" style="position:absolute; margin-top:-50px">


and I've had no luck whatsoever... Any more tips?

Comment: Can you drop a screen shot of the email showing the "white space" and post the code you are using for the email template?

Comment: OMG!!! You were spot on.  I coded it in Notepad++ b/c it's easy to read and I love hitting return and tabbing.  Didn't know that was a bad thing for SPD.  It looks fantastic now and you deserve credit for the answer.  Thank you very much!  You just made my week!!! ;-)

Cheers,
Matt